# What's a work-around for creating a master-detail relationship for Users?

Tags: user, master-detail, user-record

I'm trying to create a user-centric schema and running into the limitations of the built-in user object.

I need the following:

- Managers should see a list of all users assigned to them with a roll-up summary for some related custom objects (e.g. number of objectives completed, with objectives being custom objects)
- When a manager views a user's info, the list of related custom objects should be easily accessible (e.g. submitted reports, current objectives, etc...)
- Users should be able to easily update their own profile info (e.g. custom user fields)
- Users should be able to create custom object records and have them automatically linked to them (e.g. no need to select themselves from a drop-down list)

The natural design would be to create a master-detail relationship between the built-in User objects and the custom objects. I understand that custom objects can't be in a master-detail relationship with the User object. It also sounds like there's no easy way to get a list view of users.

What would be a workaround? If I create a custom object for users, how do I make sure a new instance automatically gets created for each user, a user can only edit their own record and users can easily find that record? Is there a way to bypass forcing users to select their record from a list of 1?

Comment: Have you tried creating a junction object? You'd have a look-up on one side to user and could have a M-D on the other side.